# Bootstrap form input change background color on text enter and revert on empty field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just need to change the background color in input field when someone fill out the field. If not, keep the default background color. Any method for doing this without extra classes in bootstrap?

I tried with but no luck. The background color will disappear when focus out.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

.form-control:active,
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:focus:active {
  background-color: #96d3ec!important;
  border-color: #96d3ec;
  color: white;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using "required" validation property to an input field:

```css
.form-control:valid {
  background-color:  #96d3ec!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Using placeholder value detection:

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
   background-color:  #96d3ec!important;
}


input:placeholder-shown {
   background-color:  #ffffff!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter a value" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Not working. Whether someone filled that field or not, It always apply blue background color to the input field.

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid : updated my answer for without required fields.

Comment: @CssSY accept the answer to close your question +1 bro!

Comment: This is working fine. What about input field without placeholder?

Comment: I was figured it out. Add placed holder with space. <input type="text" placeholder= " " class="form-control">

Comment: Not sure why this is accepted but did you consider just checking if the input is focused? Focus -> change background. Simple