# change background color when value of an input field has changed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have an angular reactive form, I would like to change the background color of all the input fields when the value is changed. Some of the input fields are pre populated and not required fields. I tried the [following solution I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258115/bootstrap-form-input-change-background-color-on-text-enter-and-revert-on-empty-f/48258157), but it requires my input fields to be required:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

```
.form-control:valid {
  background-color:  #96d3ec!important;
}
```

Wondering if form-control has anything like:

```
.form-control:changed {
  background-color:  #96d3ec!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found, doesn't require the your input fields to be required. ( The second code snippet of the solution ).

Only the first code snippet of the solution needs the required field, to ensure validation.

Answer (score 0):

Nope!you can check all the rest pseudo-classes here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid
and there's no :change pseudo class.
Please use change event to implement this function.